# When is it ever appropriate to have class and instance names be identical?

Tags: coding-style, naming-conventions

I've seen times when people will have code that looks like this:

```
class SomeClass { /* lorem ipsum */ };

int main()
{
    SomeClass someClass;
    /* dolor
       sit
       amet
    */
}
```

I feel like this is a recipe for disaster, and more importantly, the specificity is all wrong. Either the class name is too specific (and therefore not sufficiently reusable) or the instance variable is named too generally, so future programmers will not be certain what purpose it serves in the code, and as comments are usually lacking, proper naming seems important to me.

Is there *ever* a good reason to do this? I'm sincerely curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) and [Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) patterns are first things that come to my mind.

In some cases using central [Flyweight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) might also have same object name as class name.

It can be avoided for various reasons if programming language you use allows calling methods from within a class without creating actual object.

---

In general - whenever you have one very specific class that exists only in a one very specific instance you might see it being named identically. You shouldn't name classes and objects the same unless being an unique instance is part of it's functionality.

My generic advice is to avoid naming objects the same as classes like a fire, but there are circumstances and languages where having an object named identically to the class might significantly increase code readability. You need to be extra-careful with that though.

Comment: Thanks, this helps me understand. I'm not a big fan of it, but I do see now that it is logical sometimes.